# gRPC Python: Can't instantiate abstract class ServicerContext

Tags: python, testing, grpc

I am trying to test the following method:

```
def my_method(self, request, context):
    context.set_details('Already exists')
    context.set_code(grpc.StatusCode.ALREADY_EXISTS)
```

To test it, I must pass in a request and a context (which is a `grpc.ServicerContext` object), like so:

```
import grcp

def test_my_method(self):
    request = {"something": "something-else"}
    context = grpc.ServicerContext()

    my_method(request, context)

    # Assert something here
```

The problem is, I get the following error when I run my tests:

`TypeError: Can't instantiate abstract class ServicerContext with abstract methods add_callback, cancel, invocation_metadata, is_active, peer, send_initial_metadata, set_code, set_details, set_trailing_metadata, time_remaining`

How can I get a `grpc.ServicerContext` object? If I can't, how do I test the method?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`grpc.ServicerContext` is an abstract class defined with the [`abc` module](https://docs.python.org/3/library/abc.html). In your test you need to write your own concrete subclass of it and pass an instance of that to the method you are testing.